# Adding a temporary exception to App Transport xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I'm trying to connect to an insecure web server for testing purposes with my iOS 10.0 app, using xcode 8.

I modified my info.plist file to add an exception as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>http://seemeclothing.xyz/service.php</key>
            <dict>
                <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This modification does not allow me to connect.  Instead I get the following error

> practice_URL_PHP_MySQL[22723:2666126] App Transport Security has
>   blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure.
>   Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Is there a problem with my modification of info.plist or is this an xcode issue?

Answer (score 1):

The key is `NSExceptionDomains`, not `NSExceptionURIs` :)

The key should be your domain, not your uri. So just

```
<key>seemeclothing.xyz</key>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I made that change and recompiled but am still recieving the same error

Comment: I made that change to your info.plist and tested it and it worked for me.  Are you sure there isn't some other http url that your app is accessing?

Comment: Yes.  Here is my test code - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/3e373f1d6843efa0998af60f3be2a046 Without the ATS exception it doesn't fetch the data.  With it, it does

Comment: Try a cleaning your project and rebuild to make sure it is picking up the changed info.plist

Comment: Many thanks.  Was finally able to connect by pasting code into a new project.  Not sure why I couldn't clean the original.